# Attachment name and file extension not working in email *.eml

Tags: php, email, zend-framework, email-attachments, eml

I want to create email files in `.eml` format with multiple attachments in. The attachments are generated and the content of the attachments are correct. But the attachments always come in `.dat` format and the file names go as "ATT00001", "ATT0002".. etc

Currently I am following the solution given in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8776481/php-library-to-generate-eml-email-files) and my code is as follows

*PHP*

```
   foreach($reports as $pdf){
        $attachment = file_get_contents("auto_report_attachments\\Template_Attachment.eml");
        $attachment = str_replace("TEMPLATE_MIME_TYPE", $pdf['type'], $attachment);
        $attachment = str_replace("TEMPLATE_FILE_NAME", $pdf['filename'], $attachment);
        $attachment = str_replace("TEMPLATE_ATTACHMENT_CONTENT", base64_encode($pdf['file']), $attachment);

        $content .= $attachment;
        unset($attachment);
    }
```

*Template Attachment*

```
--080107000800000609090108
Content-Type: "TEMPLATE_MIME_TYPE"
name="TEMPLATE_FILE_NAME"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;
filename="TEMPLATE_FILE_NAME"

TEMPLATE_ATTACHMENT_CONTENT
```

`$content` is the main email header and body as described in the above link. My `.eml` file looks like;

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Date: Tue, 16 Apr 2013 09:03:37 +0100
From: sender@emailhost.com
To: recipient@emailhost.com
Subject: Email subject
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="080107000800000609090108"

This is a message with multiple parts in MIME format.

--080107000800000609090108
Content-Type: text/html

<p><strong>Project Name: Some Project and the body continues...</p>



--080107000800000609090108
Content-Type: "application/pdf"
name="AM22831 -  - Cover Sheet.pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;
filename="AM22831 -  - Cover Sheet.pdf"

JVBERi0xLjMKMyAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlIC9QYWdlCi9QYXJlbnQgMSAwIFIKL1Jlc291cmNlcyAyIDAgUgovQ29udGVudHMgNCAwICiUlRU9GCg==



--080107000800000609090108
Content-Type: "application/pdf"
name="AM22831 -  - Manufacturing Status.pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;
filename="AM22831 -  - Manufacturing Status.pdf"

cSAxMTMuMzkgMCAwIDMwLjUzIDE0LjE3IDU1MC41OCBjbSAvSTEgRG8gUQpxIDAuMDAwIDAuMDAwIDEuMDAwIHJnIEJUIDEzMC4zOSRU9GCg==

--080107000800000609090108
```

The above `base64` content gives the right content in the `PDF` file when the file opened by selecting to open with a `PDF Reader`. But the files do not come in `.pdf` format. Same happens for `.xls`, `.doc` and all other file types. All the files come in `.dat` format with standard naming rather than the specified names.

Please help me to solve this attachments come in the required `file type` with specified file name.

NB: The `base64` content in the sample `.eml` file is truncated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer my self..!! The header of `Template_Attachment` should be as follows

```
--080107000800000609090108
Content-Type: TEMPLATE_MIME_TYPE;name="TEMPLATE_FILE_NAME"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="TEMPLATE_FILE_NAME"

TEMPLATE_ATTACHMENT_CONTENT
```

Where `080107000800000609090108` is the boundary in this case and at the end of all attachments, there should be another `080107000800000609090108` to end the email.

Hope this would be helpful to somebody someday :-)

PS: so the actual `.eml` file would look like as follows which works perfect as it should do

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Date: Tue, 16 Apr 2013 09:03:37 +0100
From: sender@emailhost.com
To: recipient@emailhost.com
Subject: Email subject
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="080107000800000609090108"

This is a message with multiple parts in MIME format.

--080107000800000609090108
Content-Type: text/html

<p><strong>Project Name: Some Project and the body continues...</p>

--080107000800000609090108
Content-Type: application/pdf;name="AM22831 Cover Sheet.pdf"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="AM22831 Cover Sheet.pdf"

JVBERi0xLjMKMyAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlIC9QYWdlCi9QYXJlbnQgMSAwIFIKL1Jlc291cmNlcyAyIDAgUgovQ29udGVasdsDFDffjMBakdjKJHBzdHlsZT0iY29=

--080107000800000609090108
Content-Type: application/excel;name="AM22831 Manufacturing Status.xls"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="AM22831 Manufacturing Status.xls"

DQoNCjx0YWJsZSBib3JkZXI9IjAiPg0KPHRyPg0KPHRkIGNvbHNwYW49IjMiIHJvd3NwYW49IjIiIGFsaWduPSJjZW50ZXIiPg0KICAgIDxoMSBzdHlsZT0iY29=
```

Comment: This is not working.. Could you please tell which outlook client you used to open this attachment?

Comment: I developed this 7 years ago and I just checked whether this code is still working. It is actually still working and I am using MS Outlook 2010 to open the eml files. attachments can be docx, xlsx, pdf or anything like that and they open in their respective applications.